# React Js Context Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and request data from api, but it seems like my 'data' is getting error

My class as below:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

this.state = {
  UserName: '',
  Password: '',
  var:'',
}
this.Login = this.Login.bind(this);

  }

  Login(event) {
    debugger;
    api.post('/api/login', {
      UserName: this.state.UserName,
      Password: this.state.Password,
    })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.data.Status === 'Success') {
          this.setState({var: result.data.status});
          alert("User login Successfully");                                                                                                         
        } else {
          alert('Invalid User');
        }
        debugger;
      })
  }
```

I am trying to make a login.
After user make a request, I will get some data from api and *setState* my *var*

The error prompt that the my `result.data.Success` was error. I dig some research on stack overflow, it mentioned about the *Arrow Function* which I used. Or is it any snytax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is my bad.
The overall process for my login is that my API will pass back a token after user successfully login. Later on that part, in another js of mine, which exporting `default api` is using interceptors from axios.
I set a `gettoken` function there, but at first I am processing login, so no token is stored in my frontend. As in the result, interceptions return an error -- which cause undefined

My Api code as follow:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:9999/'
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.localStorgae.getItem('token');
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your api may result `undefined` as response.

**So make a check on results**

```js
.then((result) => {
        if (result && result.data.Status === 'Success') {
```

Comment: oh yes, it seems this way though, the api return an 'undefined' as response, when I try `result && result.data.Status === 'Success'`, when I try `console.log.result` it come out **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

I think that result.data.data.Status is the correct way. Or you can print it with console.log(), or debugger to see what format the result is

Comment: Do you mean I should try `result.data.data.status` instead of `result.data.status`?

Comment: Yes, you can first use postman to test if the API is available. It is also recommended not to call the API in the constructor function, but to call it in the life cycle componentDidMount()

Comment: Forgot a key point, is the data json.parse? Because some need to parse

Comment: the API is working. Well I called this *Login* function as I want to trigger it while user "onClick" on a button (which I didnt show it on above code), it was used to send username and password back to the API and verify user credential

Comment: yes it is json parse, well actually I found my problem

Comment: Can you describe your problem？